# How to change current time on remote linux server through JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am testing a security service(**running on remote linux server**) which returns me an access token which is **valid for 1 day**.

I am writing a **JMeter** script to test this scenario. Here are the steps that i want to follow:

1. Make a http token request to the service.
2. Once the access token is received, validate if it is a valid token by resending it to the security service.
3. **Change system date and increment it by 1 day so that the token becomes invalid**.
4. Once invalid, validate it again by sending it to the security service.

I am not sure how can i execute step 3 and if it is possible via JMeter in the first place.

Stuck. Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing a Java [ProcessBuilder.start()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) of the Linux [date](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) command.

One issue is that you'll need the appropriate privilege to change the system date.

It's worth noting that Linux `date` has the built-in ability to increment date values:

[How to increment a date in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706823/how-to-increment-a-date-in-a-bash-script)

```
DATE=2013-05-25

for i in {0..8} do
  NEXT_DATE=$(date +%m-%d-%Y -d "$DATE + $i day") 
  echo $NEXT_DATE 
done
```

produces:

```
05-25-2013 
05-26-2013 
....
05-31-2013 
06-01-2013 
06-02-2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you need to deal with **remote** linux system you'll need to change date somehow via SSH channel. So I would recommend doing it as follows:

1. Download [JSch.jar](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) file (Java library which allows SSH and SCP protocols manipulations from Java code) and drop it to /lib folder of your JMeter installation. JMeter restart will be required to pick the .jar up.
2. Add a [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) to your test plan where you need to change remote linux system time
3. Put the following code into the Beanshell Sampler's "Script" area:

   ```
   import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
   import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
   import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
   import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

   JSch jSch = new JSch();
   Session session = jSch.getSession("root", "your.host", 22);
   session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
   session.setPassword("your password");
   session.connect();

   Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

   String command = "date -s \"$(date --date \"+1 day\")\"";
   ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
   channel.setInputStream(null);
   ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
   InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

   channel.connect();
   StringBuilder rv = new StringBuilder();
   rv.append("New system date: ");
   byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
   while (true) {
     while (in.available() > 0) {
         int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
         if (i < 0) break;
         rv.append(new String(tmp, 0, i));
     }
     if (channel.isClosed()) {
         break;
     }
     try {
         Thread.sleep(100);
     } catch (Exception ee) {
         ee.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
   in.close();
   channel.disconnect();
   session.disconnect();        
   SampleResult.setResponseData(rv.toString().getBytes());
   ```
4. Beanshell Sampler response data will look something like:

   ```
   New system date: Mon Apr 13 10:16:48 BST 2015
   ```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) to learn how to enhance your test with scripting where JMeter doesn't offer required test element.

Comment: I tried your code but the new date is not reflecting on the remote linux server.

Comment: I'm not telepathic enough to "suggest" unless I see your sampler response and jmeter.log file.