# Create a date table in hive

Tags: hive, calendar, hiveql, date-range

How to create a table in hive which should have all the dates from 1st Jan 2016 till today (01-01-2016 to 12-10-2016)?

The table would have only one column i.e. the date column.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generate days from date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)

Comment: Generate date table in Hive: stackoverflow.com/a/55440454/2700344

Answer (score 3):

You can generate this data yourself.

---

Go to Hive shell and execute :

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (col1 date)
```

Default format for Date type in hive : YYYY-­MM-­DD. So we will generate data in this format.

Now generate data using [shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18707392/3929393). Open terminal and fire :

`gedit /tmp/test.sh`

Copy this code :

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=2016-01-01
for i in {0..285}
do
   NEXT_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$DATE + $i day")
   echo "$NEXT_DATE"
done
```

You don't have execute permission by default, use :

```
chmod 777 /tmp/test.sh
```

Now fire :

```
/tmp/test.sh >/tmp/test.csv
```

You got data in `test.csv`

```
2016-01-01
2016-01-02
2016-01-03
2016-01-04
........
```

Now go back to hive shell and fire :

```
load data local inpath '/tmp/test.csv' into table tbl1;
```

*Your table with data is ready.*

Answer (score 1):

You can download Date dimension in excel format from the [Kimball Group](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/books/microsoft-data-warehouse-dw-toolkit/)

Save Excel as csv, put in HDFS, create an external table on top of it.

I suggest you to create date_dim and keep all the columns in it. Date dimension should be in the warehouse. You can select only date column or create a view with necessary columns.

Also you can generate date range in Hive, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55440454/2700344

Comment: It can be used to check the valid dates as a look up table. Nice

Comment: @vikrantrana Calendar can be generated also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55440454/2700344