# How can i generate a Date table with fields equals to "Dayofweek", "weekofyear" etc ;and rows equals to date from 2010-01-01 till current_date

Tags: sql, sql-server, hive, calendar, date-range

How can i generate a Date table with fields like "Dayofweek", "weekofyear" etc ;and rows equals to date from 2010-01-01 till current_date
like below:

```
             Dayofweek   Dayofmonth  Dayofyear Weekofmonth Weekofyear Holiday
2010-01-01       6           1            1          1          1        Y
2010-01-02       7           2            2          1          1        N
2010-01-03       1           3            3          1          1        N
.....
2019-03-31       1           31           90         6         14        N
```

> P.S. DayofWeek = day num of the week, Sun = 1, Sat = 7
>        Dayofmonth = day num of the month

```
 Holiday is a flag to distinguish whether the records is a public holiday
```

So first step i need to do may be create records from 2010-01-01 till current_date, i wonder while loop in hive and mssql will do?
Then I have the column ready
Finally combine them.

I have tried

```
"Declare @startdate date
Declare @enddate date

set @startdate = '2010-01-01'
set @end_date = current_date

while @ start_date <=end_date
BEGIN
    DATEADD(DAY,1,@startdate)
END

"Declare @startdate date
Declare @enddate date

set @startdate = '2010-01-01'
set @end_date = current_date

while @ start_date <=end_date
BEGIN
    DATEADD(DAY,1,@startdate)
END

             Dayofweek   Dayofmonth  Dayofyear Weekofmonth Weekofyear Holiday
2010-01-01       6           1            1          1          1        Y
2010-01-02       7           2            2          1          1        N
2010-01-03       1           3            3          1          1        N
.....
2019-03-31       1           31           90         6         14        N
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Hive:

```
set hivevar:start_date=2010-01-01; --replace with your start_date
set hivevar:end_date=current_date; --replace with your end_date

with date_range as 
(--this query generates date range
select date_add ('${hivevar:start_date}',s.i) as dt 
  from ( select posexplode(split(space(datediff(${hivevar:end_date},'${hivevar:start_date}')),' ')) as (i,x) ) s
),

holiday as (
select stack(5, --add more
             '01-01', 'New Year',
             '01-21', 'Martin Luther King Day',
             '02-18', 'Presidents Day',
             '05-27', 'Memorial Day',
             '07-04', 'Independence Day'
        ) as ( mtdt,holiday_name)
) 

select d.dt                                 as date,
       date_format(current_date,'u')        as dayofweek,
       day(dt)                              as dayofmonth,
       date_format(current_date,'D')        as dayofyear,
       date_format(current_date,'W')        as weekofmonth,
       weekofyear(dt)                       as weekofyear, 
       case when h.mtdt is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as Holiday,
       h.holiday_name
  from date_range d 
       left join holiday h on substr(d.dt,6)= h.mtdt
;
```

Add more holidays.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a calendar table with the following solution:

```
SELECT calendar.*, 
    DATEPART(dw, calendar.date_value) AS DayOfWeek, 
    DATEPART(dd, calendar.date_value) AS DayOfMonth, 
    DATEPART(dy, calendar.date_value) AS DayOfYear,
    DATEPART(wk, calendar.date_value) AS WeekOfYear, 
    CASE WHEN holidays.date_value IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'J' END AS Holiday 
FROM (
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, t4 * 10000 + t3 * 1000 + t2 * 100 + t1 * 10 + t0, '1970-01-01') AS date_value FROM
    (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
    (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
    (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
    (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
    (SELECT 0 t4 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4
) calendar INNER JOIN (
  SELECT '2010-01-01' AS date_value UNION SELECT '2010-01-06'
) holidays ON calendar.date_value = holidays.date_value
WHERE calendar.date_value BETWEEN CAST('2010-01-01' AS DATE) AND GETDATE()
ORDER BY calendar.date_value
```

The basic calendar table is based on [this solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45992247/3840840). With the `INNER JOIN` you can add some holidays.

With [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) you can get some information about the date.