# How can i do a rolling 12 month sum when some year month values are missing?

Tags: sql, hive

I am calculating rolling sum as such:

```
select
    city,
    month_year,
    person,
    sum(total) over (partition by person,city order by month_year rows between 11 preceding and current row) rolling_one_year
from
    (select
      city,
      month_year,
      person,
      sum(amount_dollar) as total
    from db1 d

    group by 1,2,3) ;
```

however sometimes  the not every person has a month_year value: e.g. a rolling 12 year some is as below IF we had consecutive month values:

[image]

but what if a month was missing for person e.g. 202208, according to the logic above it would calculate the following 202201 - 202301 which as we know 13 months.

[image]

How can i adapt my code above to ensure that the range of months selected is within 1 year?

Comment: You could create a date table that you join to and use the date table to go back 12 months, then it wont matter if your missing a month in your data, because you will be looking at 12 months in your date lookup table for the dates, but adding up/summing up your data that could be missing a month

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to LEFT JOIN your data to the calendar table.

Here is a guide on how to create the calendar table if you don't have one.
[Create a date table in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000079/create-a-date-table-in-hive)