# How to subtract or add date from a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, date

I have a date in the variable `x=20170402`, getting this value from another file.
I want to modify this by adding/subtracting and save to new variable. How can i do this?
ex: if i subtract one day, `y=20170401`; two days, `y=20170331`
and it is GNU based.

Comment: do you have `GNU date`? or `FreeBSD` one? output `date --version`?

Comment: Also can you provide an exact output you need for your input? This information is not sufficient

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increment a date in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18706823/608639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `GNU date` it can be done quite easily with its `-d` switch.

```
x=20170402
date -d "$x -1 days" "+%Y%m%d"
20170401
```

and for 2 days

```
date -d "$x - 2 days" "+%Y%m%d"
20170331
```

Answer (score 3):

The command date should be enough.

```
$ x=20170402;
$ date -d "$x 1 day ago" +'%Y%m%d'
20170401

$ date -d "$x 2 day ago" +'%Y%m%d'
20170331
```

Answer (score 0):

`-d` flag for this would serve the purpose. `$Number` is the number of days you wish to substract.

```
x=20170402
past_date=$(date -d "$x - $Number days" +%Y%m%d)
echo "$past_date"
```