# Add X days to a particular date in BASH

Tags: bash, macos, date

Totally new to BASH. Apologies in advance.

---

**Problem**

I'd like to add X days to a specific date.

---

**Code**

I figured out that `date` in BASH retrieves the current date.

I also figured out that I can add X days to the current date in the following way,

```
expiration_date=$ date -v +1d
```

which gives,

```
Tue Sep 26 20:28:13 CEST 2017
```

which is indeed the date of writing plus `X=1` days.

---

**Question**

In stead of `date` in the command line above, I'd like to insert a particular date to which X days will be added, e.g. 20/09/2017.

Don't care about the format of the particular date.

In other words: How do I make the following work,

```
expiration_date=$ '20/09/2017' -v +1d
```

---

Tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706823/how-to-increment-a-date-in-a-bash-script), but doesn't do what I want.

---

Edit: Did not know things are different for OSX.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
dt='2017-09-20'

date -d "$dt +1 day"
Thu Sep 21 00:00:00 EDT 2017

date -d "$dt +2 day"
Fri Sep 22 00:00:00 EDT 2017
```

---

It seems OP is using OSX. You can use date addition this way:

```
s='20/09/2017'
date -j -v +1d -f "%d/%m/%Y" "$s"

Thu Sep 21 14:49:51 EDT 2017
```

Comment: Thank you. My terminal shows me this when I do your command: `usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`. Not sure what to do?

Comment: Are you on OSX? This date command I provided is for `gnu date`. On my OSX I got it using `brew` installer.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Did not know things are different on OSX.

Comment: Last question. If I want to assign the addition result to a variable and call it, how would I do that? I.e. a correct form of `end=(date -j -v +1d -f "%d/%m/%Y" "$s")`, `echo end`.

Comment: Use `end=$(...)`

Comment: I tried that, e.g. `end=$(date -j -v +1d -f "%d/%m/%Y" "$s”)`, but then terminal states `./test.txt: line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"''`./test.txt: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: Ok, I fumbled around with i.a. white spaces and found that `end=$( date -j -v +30d -f "%d/%m/%Y" "$s")
echo $end` works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
date -d "Sun Sep 6 02:00:00 IST 2012+10 days"
```

Comment: Not working in OSX