# Bash increment timestamp by 1 day subtracting from hour

Tags: bash, shell, timestamp

I have a bash script which is supposed to increment a timestamp by 1 day to echo the next 5 days from the timestamp, however when it is run it produces the wrong output and has subtracted one hour instead.

Script

```
#!/bin/bash

TIME_STAMP="2023-06-03 06:21:33"

for i in {1..5}
do
    NEXT_DATE=$(date "+%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S" -d "$TIME_STAMP +$i day")
    echo $NEXT_DATE
done
```

Output

```
2023-04-06 06:21:33
2023-04-06 05:21:33
2023-04-06 04:21:33
2023-04-06 03:21:33
2023-04-06 02:21:33
```

As far as I can tell the date format is correct so I've got absouletly no idea why it isn't working correctly. If there's an easier way to do this I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increment a date in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706823/how-to-increment-a-date-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: As the accepted answer in the other question mentions: `NEXT_DATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d "$TIME_STAMP UTC +$i day")`

Comment: Or, simply split off the time and just add that back on after the generated date. `for i in {1..5}; do     NEXT_DATE=$(date "+%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S" -d "${TIME_STAMP% *} +$i days ${TIME_STAMP#* }");     echo $NEXT_DATE; done`

Comment: @Paolo this is not a duplicate of [how-to-increment-a-date-in-a-bash-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706823/how-to-increment-a-date-in-a-bash-script) as that question doesn't have a time associated with the starting date.

Comment: @EdMorton in this question OP is literally asking how to increase by days, which is exactly the same thing being asked in the question I linked

Comment: @Paolo the OP is not asking how to increase a **date** by days as in the question you linked, they're asking how to increase a **timestamp** (date+time) by days which is what makes this a different question. The accepted answer for THAT question is the same as the code in THIS question which does not work for that reason - it's not the same question and it requires a different answer.

Comment: Paolo: here there's a special caveat, because `date -d` bug on appending N days to a date string in case you specify hours:minutes:secondes. It's a corner case, better to have it for the records. This is not _that_ simple as other said 'duplicated answer'

Comment: @EdMorton I think you are doing quite the nitpicking here, I've seen questions closed as duplicates for way less. The accepted answer to the other question even mentions how to resolve this OP's question... whatever. Thought you were by the book!

Comment: @Paolo the question has been open about 45 minutes and has 4 answers so far, so I don't think it's nitpicking to assume it deserves an answer but if it is nitpicking then multiple people are doing it, maybe you should discuss with them too? Thank you for considering me as someone who goes by the book.

Answer (score 1):

I think [@KamilCuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76064844/1745001) is the right approach if you're going to use `date` for this but here's an alternative assuming you don't care about DST:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

this_time_stamp='2023-06-03 06:21:33'

for i in {1..5}
do
    this_date="${this_time_stamp% *}"
    this_time="${this_time_stamp#* }"
    next_time_stamp="$(date '+%Y-%d-%m' -d "$this_date +$i day") $this_time"
    echo "$next_time_stamp"
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
2023-04-06 06:21:33
2023-05-06 06:21:33
2023-06-06 06:21:33
2023-07-06 06:21:33
2023-08-06 06:21:33
```

See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) for why I changed your variable names to lower case.

I'd strongly recommend you do not use a `YYYY-DD-MM` instead of `YYYY-MM-DD` or similar format, by the ,as it's hard to do anything with that afterwards, e.g. sorting or searching in a range.

Comment: Why are you answering a duplicate?

Comment: @Paolo It's not a duplicate of the question you suggested as that question doesn't have a time associated with the starting date. idk if there's some other question it IS a duplicate of.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the date string is being split and `date` only calculates something based on the time.

A workaround is to split off the time and add it back on after the generated date.

```
for i in {1..5}; do
     NEXT_DATE=$(date "+%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S" -d "${TIME_STAMP% *} +$i days ${TIME_STAMP#* }")
     echo "$NEXT_DATE"
done
```

Capturing the output in a variable just so you can then `echo` it is a [useless `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) but I imagine you want the variable for something more involved in your real use case.

Notice also that `date -d` is not portable; this will work on Linux, but not on many other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The string is parsed as:

- +$i - timezone in the format +HH
- day - add a day

Add a `+00` to make `date` parse the timezone as UTC.

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do NEXT_DATE=$(date "+%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S" -d "$TIME_STAMP +00 +$i day"); echo $NEXT_DATE; done
2023-04-06 08:21:33
2023-05-06 08:21:33
2023-06-06 08:21:33
2023-07-06 08:21:33
2023-08-06 08:21:33
```

or to use your current timezone offset:

```
$ tz=$(date +'%z')
$ for i in {1..5}; do NEXT_DATE=$(date "+%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S" -d "$TIME_STAMP $tz +$i day"); echo $NEXT_DATE; done
2023-04-06 06:21:33
2023-05-06 06:21:33
2023-06-06 06:21:33
2023-07-06 06:21:33
2023-08-06 06:21:33
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Perl` with *core modules* (installed by default), without 'cheating' with date string, the most portable and robust solution I guess.
wink to @Ed ;)

```
perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -sE '
    foreach my $i (1..5) {
        my $d = Time::Piece->strptime($mydate, "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S");
        ($dow, $month, $dom, $hour, $year) = split / +/, $d +$i*ONE_DAY;
        my $dateold = Time::Piece->strptime(
            "$dow $month $dom $year $hour",
            "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S");
        say $dateold->strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S");
    }
' -- -mydate='2023-06-03 06:21:33'
```

```
2023-07-03 06:21:33
2023-08-03 06:21:33
2023-09-03 06:21:33
2023-10-03 06:21:33
2023-11-03 06:21:33
```

Comment: I wanted to just upvote the wink :-).

Answer (score 0):

Simple,instead local time zone, we can use `date` with `-u` option for UTC zone, add '0000' in input time zone for UTC conversion

```
#!/bin/bash
UTC="2023-06-03 06:21:33+0000"
for days in {1..5}
do
    DATE_NEXT=$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d "$UTC +$days day")
    echo $DATE_NEXT
done

output:

2023-06-04 06:21:33
2023-06-05 06:21:33
2023-06-06 06:21:33
2023-06-07 06:21:33
2023-06-08 06:21:33
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the + sign is interpreted as timezone. We can just remove it:

```bash
for (( i=1 ; i<= 5 ; ++i )); do
    NEXT_DATE=$(date "+%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S" -d "$TIME_STAMP $i day")
    echo "$NEXT_DATE"
done

OUTPUT:
2023-04-06 06:21:33
2023-05-06 06:21:33
2023-06-06 06:21:33
2023-07-06 06:21:33
2023-08-06 06:21:33
```

In the same way, there is the same problem for previous days.
In that case, we can use `"$TIME_STAMP $i day ago"` instead

I also remove the `seq`: it is always better to use C-style loops as `seq` is an external command and require to place the entire sequence in a buffer before splitting it into integers